# How can I merge columns in UI-grid?

Tags: angularjs, ui-grid

Is there any way to merge the columns of UI-grid to be appear as continuous row (without any column line in between). I have tried this
[merge columns in ui grid](http://plnkr.co/edit/VePql6XmNMbYBOpgHswk?p=preview)

but this causes me loss of row data at row number number 1. Even more I want every alternate row to be merged.

> Here is my Html

```
<div id="grid" ui-grid="gridOptions" ui-grid-move-columns ui-grid-resize-columns ui-grid-auto-resize class="grid"></div>
```

> Here is my js code for grid

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
    enableColumnResizing: true,
    enableRowHeaderSelection: false,
    enableGridMenu: true,
    enableHorizontalScrollbar: 0,
    enableVerticalScrollbar: 2,
    enableColumnMenus: false,
    enableRowSelection: true,
    columnDefs: [
   {
       name: 'Code',
       field: 'Code',
   }, {
       name: 'Title',
       field: 'Title',
   }, {
       name: 'Visits',
       field: 'Visit',
   }, {
       name: 'UsedVisits',
       field: 'usedVisits',
   }, {
       name: 'Pending Visits',
       field: 'pendingVisits',
   }, {
       name: 'Available Visits',
       field: 'availableVisits',
   }, {
       name: 'Start Date',
       field: 'StartDate',
   }, {
       name: 'End Date',
       field: 'EndDate',
   }, {
       name: 'Status',
       field: 'Status',
   }
    ]
};
```

Please suggest me something, 
Thank you

Comment: Hi, sameer 
Do you want to merge column or just you want column to be appeared as continous columns without borders ?

Comment: any of two will work but i want every alternate row to be merged

Comment: Can you explain it with example, what i got is first and second row should  come as one row and third and fourth row should come as second row ?

Comment: yeah, I added foreach there and calculated odd and even number of row, but this is not working.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview this is original link

Answer (score 0):

To implement it we can merge data while creating array for grid itself

using logic
 originally we have array which we merge to show in grid so that in grid we can get merged data

```
  $scope.myData = [{name: "1Abcd", age: "one", gender:2},
               {name: "2Tom", age: "two", gender:1},
               {name: "3Abcd", age: "three", gender:2},
               {name: "4Abcd", age: "four", gender:2},
               {name: "5Abcd", age: "five", gender:2},
               {name: "6Abcd", age: "six", gender:2},
               {name: "7Abcd", age: "seven", gender:2},
               {name: "8Abcd", age: "eight", gender:2},
               {name: "9Abcd", age: "nine", gender:2},

              ];

$scope.myDataNew =[]     ;    

for(var i=0;i<(($scope.myData.length/2)+1);i++){
var tempObj ={};
if($scope.myData[i*2] && $scope.myData[i*2].name && $scope.myData[i*2+1] &&$scope.myData[i*2+1].name){
 tempObj.name =$scope.myData[i*2].name+$scope.myData[i*2+1].name ;
 }
 else if($scope.myData[i*2] && $scope.myData[i*2].name &&    !$scope.myData[i*2+1] ){
tempObj.name =$scope.myData[i*2].name;
 }
if($scope.myData[i*2] && $scope.myData[i*2].age && $scope.myData[i*2+1]    &&$scope.myData[i*2+1].age){
tempObj.age =$scope.myData[i*2].age+$scope.myData[i*2+1].age ;
}else if($scope.myData[i*2] && $scope.myData[i*2].age &&    !$scope.myData[i*2+1] )
{
tempObj.age =$scope.myData[i*2].age;
}

$scope.myDataNew.push(tempObj);
}
```

here is code pen for completed implementation
http://codepen.io/vkvicky-vasudev/pen/LRPNyL

If ant change required feel free to inform me