# Table with two headers and 3 columns

Tags: javascript, angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

I'm struggling with creating a table which looks like this in UI-GRID.

```
| HEADER1 |     HEADER2     |
| h1val1  | h2val1 | h2val1 |
| h1val2  | h2val1 | h2val1 |
| h1val3  | h2val1 | h2val1 |
```

Could someone help me how to organize data in myData and columnDefs (gridOptions) to get this kind of table?

Thanks in advance

EDIT: I need this to be working in UI-GRID

Comment: @Rajesh yes, it's that simple in html but I need this to be working in ui-grid

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39218778/how-can-i-merge-columns-in-ui-grid

Comment: This is a known [issue](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/issues/644). A user has made a [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Gw7KyA?p=preview). You can take it as reference.